# SASS function for @extend

Tags: css, function, sass

What I'm trying to achieve, is simply a shorter version of the `@extend` function in sass.

I have a heap of classes which I use all over my site for layout.

**Example:**

```
.grid1 {width:40px;}
.grid2 {width:80px;}
.grid3 {width:120px;}
.grid4 {width:160px;}
.grid5 {width:200px;}
```

I know you can use the extend function to remove duplicate css all over the site with:

`.class {@extend .grid1}`

which would output

`.class {width:40px}`

What I'm after is something a little more simple.

`.class{grid(1)};`

Here's what I've tried:

```
@function grid($n){
  @extend unquote(".grid#{$n}");
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@functions` in SASS are meant to be used to manipulate values. So the reason why this will not work is due to the fact that you are trying to return selectors and declaration blocks. This is what `mixins` are for.

One way of doing this would be:

```
$grids: ((5, 40), (10, 80), (15, 120), (20, 160));

@mixin grid($n, $fluid: false) {
    @if($fluid) {
        width: nth(nth($grids, $n), 1) + "%";
    } @else {
        width: nth(nth($grids, $n), 2) + "px";
    }
}

.foo {
  @include grid(3);
}

.bar {
   @include grid(4, true);
}
```

Which produces:

```
.foo {
  width: "120px"; }

.bar {
  width: "20%"; }
```

Comment: I think I am probably over thinking this, I already have a function that generates the grid css, I should just be re using this, but your solution works so I'll make it the correct one :) thanks dude!

Comment: Well, thanks and no problem. :) But maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Maybe you did :) Seeing as it is really a totally new question, I did post my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336526/scss-reusable-function

would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Functions for Sass do not need to be done in Ruby.  Sass has its own `@function` construct for creating functions.  Creating functions in Ruby is typically only done when Sass lacks the necessary functionality to create it (eg. a search and replace function, or a function to check the file system).